# Magento - error during module installation

Tags: php, magento

I am getting the below error even if the memory limit is more than 756M.
I have restarted the Apache and MySQL server as well.

**PHP Settings Check**

***Your current PHP memory limit is 700M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more. As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again.***

Comment: Error ?? It was clearly asking you to allocate some memory limit. Are you working on Localhost (WAMP or XAMPP)?

Comment: Search for memory_limit in your php.ini and inrease the value to something higher than 756M??

Comment: I am working on Localhost XAMPP. I have increased the memory limit to 1200M.. but still, the issue persists.